# How to check if an entity exists in the Datastore in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Okay, the scenario is the following:

I have an Entity of kind `Email` with a property `name`:

```
Entity email = new Entity("Email");
email.setProperty("name", "John");
datastore.put(email);
```

What I want to check is if exists an entity of kind `Email` with the property `name` equal to `John`. It is possible to make that in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: Override the equals method in Entity and check if the property matches.

Comment: Factory of Entity and override the equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property "name" is indexed, so you can run a query on Email entity to check if an entity (or entities) with this name already exist. For example:

```
Query q = new Query("Email");
q.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "John");
List<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
if (entities.isEmpty()) {
    // no entities with name "John"
}
```